# Difference between show up and appear

Tags: verbs

Is there any diffrence among usage of two verbs .I mean i can make sentence with “ appear “ as below :

> It **appears** that they will come by bus.

Can i use show up instead of appear in this sentence like

> It **shows up** that they will come by bus.

Comment: "Appear" has a number of meanings; "show up" is a casual/informal synonym for one of them.

Answer (score 4):

### "Appear" has two meanings, your example does *not* use the one meaning "Show Up"

The word *appear* can mean "seem, give the impression of being" or "become seen/visible."

In your first sentence, *appear* has the first meaning, but it is the second that is synonymous with "show up."

So you could never say "It shows up that ... " Here are some examples of the word *appear* being used for both meanings:

> They appeared on the bus. *(Showed up)*
>
> They appeared **to be** on the bus. *(They gave the impression of being on the bus)*

Note that the "seem" meaning is used with the stative verb "to be", while the other meaning uses a transitive or intransitive verb.

Comment: Or "It *looks like* they will come by bus."

Answer (score 0):

The verb **show up** means to arrive,  to attend a gathering or event, to be present.

> Did Mike show up at the party?  He said he might have to work.
>
> I waited all day, but the package never showed up.